# Why does this code produce an indent/syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to have the user enter an 8 digit barcode. If the code is not 8 digits long, it prints an error message. If it is 8 digits long, it raises an error.

```
def get_user_input():
    global total_price
    """ get input from user """
while len(str(GTIN))!=8:
    try:
        GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number:"))
        if len(str(GTIN))!=8:
            print("make sure the length of the barcode is 8")
        else:
            print("make sure you enter a valid number")
        return GTIN
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you get. Please share the error/stack trace.

Comment: I get an unexpeced indent on the next line after this function

Comment: Please make sure your indentation is correct as you've pasted it, because right now your `while` is at the main execution level, *not* inside your `get_user_input` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually several errors going on here:

1. Your indentation was being processed as the while loop being outside the function. Witespace in Python matters.
2. It is required to have an except with every try statement.
3. Additionally, GTIN was never initially defined, I fixed that.

Your new code:

```
def get_user_input():
    global total_price
    """ get input from user """
    GTIN = ""
    while True:
        try:
            GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number:"))
            if len(str(GTIN)) == 8:
                break
            else:
                print("make sure the length of the barcode is 8")
        except:
            pass
    return GTIN
get_user_input()
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'GTIN' referenced before assignment

Comment: Just updated it.  If you could mark as solution, it would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you , it works , however How would I make it continue , if i Input a input less than 8 the error comes up , however if i input it again the code just continues

Comment: Click the green tick next to the upvote and down vote.  Additionally, updated the code.